# iOS - sending data between two apps on two devices

Tags: ios

Trying to figure out the most efficient way of sending data between one app (app1) on a device (dev1), to another different app (app2) on another device (dev2). Initially I thought this would be done through some type of web service, however, I was hoping there is something in the iOS SDK. If there is... how exactly can it be done (maybe by using URLS or Bonjour)? I can't find a clear answer when searching the web.

App1 on dev1 generates some sort of data -> app2 on dev2 receives and uses this data for its own purposes.

...The apps are also meant to be used in the same general area, however I worry that bluetooth range might be a problem

Comment: bluetooth... you did not specify in your question that these devices are not in the same room.

Comment: @Almo you're right, I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both application is developed by you, then for sharing data I'll suggest the following techniques :

1. [**Bonjour**](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)
2. [**iCloud**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: yes to clarify, both apps are developed by the same developer

Comment: @Mrambo: Please check the links of sample tutorial and sample code

Comment: I used GameKit to solve that kind of problem in my app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @SaschaHameister: It uses Bluetooth technology, right ?

Comment: Yes, it uses Bluetooth. I did experiments with up to 10 meters after the connection was established.

Comment: @MidhunMP which of the two would you recommend using, assuming bluetooth is not an option...

Comment: @Mrambo: I prefer `iCloud`. It won't have any range restrictions (Only internet connection needed)